# Cannot use Debugger in Codeblocks for AVR-Project

Tags: codeblocks, mingw-w64

I am trying to code a new AVR project in Code::Blocks (using Ubuntu). However, every time I try to build my project the following error message appears:
**Current compiler 'GNU GCC Compiler for AVR' doesn't have correctly defined debugger!**

I already installed mingw64 using  "sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64". However, it seems that the debugger didn't install properly. [I may thought, that I have to choose one of these files, but nothing seems to fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13BGS.png). Is there something I have to do additionally. Looking forward to your replies

Answer (score 0):

First, how are you using MinGW-w64 on Linux?
Secondly, you should set a correct debugger in Settings->Debugger, add the right executable path in GDB/CDB Debugger->Default. Open Settings->Compiler, in Toolchain Executable, choose the GDB/CDB:Default Debugger in the Debugger column. Then you can well build your project.